# Add system password while running the .sh file

Tags: boot, command-line, bash, scripts, services

My problem is when my pc start I want to disable mysql service with below command

```
sudo service mysql stop || service mysql stop
```

in both case system is asking for system password so I am entering the password manually everytime

I make one .sh file with above command

So how do I set & pass my system password with above script so do dont' enter password everytime when this script run.

Comment: `sudo` has the `-S, --stdin` option for that …. But, you can disable the service in `systemd`  or add your command to `root`'s crontsb as much better/safer alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The better/safer alternatives are:

- Disable the `mysql.service` unit in `systemd` like so:

  ```
  sudo systemctl disable mysql.service
  ```

  This way, the Mysql server will not be started automatically at boot but can be started manually anytime when needed.
- Add your command/s to `root`s crontab to run after boot like so:

  ```
  sudo crontab -e
  ```

  then, add a line using `systemd`'s service operations like so:

  ```
  @reboot sleep 20 && /usr/bin/systemctl stop mysql.service
  ```

  or, using `/etc/init.d/mysql` like this:

  ```
  @reboot sleep 20 && /etc/init.d/mysql stop
  ```

  or, even using `/usr/sbin/service` like this:

  ```
  @reboot sleep 20 && /usr/sbin/service mysql stop
  ```

  Notice the use of full path to executable files is a good measure in crontab and the addition of the `sleep` call to delay the execution until the service has started and became responsive.

---

However, [`sudo`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/sudo.8.html) has an `-S, --stdin` option:

> ```
> -S, --stdin
>      Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from
>      the standard input instead of using the terminal device.
> ```

That can be used like so:

```bash
echo 'PASSWORD' | /usr/bin/sudo --stdin /usr/bin/systemctl stop mysql.service
```

or, like so:

```bash
echo 'PASSWORD' | /usr/bin/sudo --stdin /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

or, like so:

```bash
echo 'PASSWORD' | /usr/bin/sudo --stdin /usr/sbin/service mysql stop
```

**However, this method is not recommended as it will save and pass your password in plane text not to mention other safety hazards involved with this method.**

Notice as well that with `sudo` and if your commands are nested with `||`, `&&` or `;` operators/separators, you will need to use `sudo` on both sides of those separators when needed for each single command or otherwise, the side that doesn't have `sudo` before its command will execute with normal user privileges and **not** super user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to enter your system password every time the script runs, you can use the sudoers file to grant permission to the user to execute the sudo command without entering a password.

Here are the steps you can follow:

Open the sudoers file using the visudo command:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following line at the end of the file, replacing username with your actual username:

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service mysql stop
```

This line grants permission to the user to execute the service mysql stop command as a superuser without entering a password.

Save and exit the file.
With this configuration, when you run your script, the `sudo` command will not ask for a password, and the script will be able to stop the MySQL service without any manual intervention.

Comment: This method, however, is not limited to the script/startup command described in the OP ... i.e. any other script or user entered command with `sudo service mysql stop` will immediately execute anytime all the time which might not be desired or at least requires a warning included in the answer.