# SUDO_ASKPASS not working

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo, virtual-console

I would like to create a simple script to download and install a program over ssh.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcher Rechner?"
read nummer
echo "Verbinde zu APC "$nummer
apc=apc$nummer.local
sshpass -f .pass_file scp $HOME/autoconfig/.filius_update.sh dvadmin@$apc:$HOME/
sshpass -f .pass_file scp $HOME/autoconfig/filiusurl dvadmin@$apc:$HOME/
sshpass -f .pass_file scp $HOME/autoconfig/.pass_file.sh dvadmin@$apc:$HOME/.pass_file.sh
sshpass -f .pass_file ssh dvadmin@$apc 'export SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.pass_file.sh; sudo -A chmod +x ./.filius_update.sh && ./.filius_update.sh'
sshpass -f .pass_file ssh dvadmin@$apc 'export SUDO_ASKPASS=${HOME}/.pass_file.sh; sudo -A rm ./.pass_file.sh && rm filius.deb && rm filiusurl && rm .filius_update.sh'
```

But the terminal send me an error that I have to configure askpass:

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: A password is required
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: A password is required
```

I don't understand what did I wrong.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: You are running `sudo` in a remote shell without a terminal device ... As a security feature `sudo` requires the password to be intered/transmitted through a terminal/virtual terminal device ... See for example similar [sudo: unable to allocate pty: No such device](https://askubuntu.com/q/1449413) ... Also see the part about `sudo -S` here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1465841

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not sure even `SUDO_ASKPASS` can work in a remote shell like that ... I haven't tested it to confirm, but in theory it shouldn't work that way(*at least not with available normal methods/mechanisms*) ...  You most likely need to look into alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

now I use

```
sshpass -f .pass_file ssh dvadmin@$apc '$HOME/.pass_file.sh | sudo -S chmod +x ./.filius_update.sh && ./.filius_update.sh'
```

and it finally works :)
I don't know why my old way doesn't work anymore but I've a solution and now I have to edit my other scripts :/