# Script to kill procees in boot not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Everytime i boot my computer i run:

1. sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
2. then look for the PID of 'mysqld' and run 'sudo kill [PID]'

I tried with this script (I also open docker desktop on startup), but didn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl --user start docker-desktop
MYSQLD_PID=$(sudo lsof -t -i:3306)
sudo kill $MYSQLD_PID
```

Also tried searching the command 'mysqld' and getting it PID and then kill it but also didn't work.

After saving the script I `chmod +x ~/startup.sh` and added it to the 'Startup Applications'

Any ideas? Thanks!

ant other ideas?

Comment: `sudo` in startup applications ... Unsuccessful combination AFAIK ... Use `root`'s crontab or a systemd system service instead without `sudo` of course ... Also, related https://askubuntu.com/q/1459859

Comment: Also `mysqld` is the daemon itself and it should be started at boot by the `mysql` service … So `sudo systemctl disable mysql` should disable the service so the daemon isn’t going to be started at boot if that is what you want.

Comment: See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1465841